# Android SimpleCursorAdapter set images

Tags: android, android-listview, simplecursoradapter

Here is a code for setting data to the list:

```
ca = new ContactsAdapter();
        ca.open(getApplicationContext());

        c = ca.fetchAllContacts();

        startManagingCursor(c);

        if(c!=null){
            SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.contacts_row,
                c,
                new String[] {c.getColumnName(1), c.getColumnName(2)},
                new int[] {R.id.c_title,R.id.c_description});
            setListAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

I need to append different images to the ImageView for each 5 rows. The images are not stored in the DB, they are stored in `drawable` folder. Should I use `ViewBinder` or there is any simpler way? If `ViewBinder` then how should I modify it?

```
 ViewBinder viewBinder = new ViewBinder() {

        public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor c, int columnIndex) {
        ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);

        Drawable myDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pmuaiso);
        Bitmap bitimage = ((BitmapDrawable) myDrawable).getBitmap();

        image.setImageBitmap(bitimage);
        return true;

        }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend the SimpleCursorAdapter class. Here's a snippet from one of my projects:

```
public class CustomSimpleCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter 
{
    public CustomSimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to, int flags) 
    {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);

        this.setViewBinder(new ViewBinder() 
        {
            @Override
            public boolean setViewValue(View view, Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) 
            {
                switch(view.getId())
                {
                    case R.id.item_yyyy:
                    {
                        ((TextView) view).setTextColor(color);
                        ((TextView) view).setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBase.JURNAL_YEAR)));
                        break;
                    }
                    case R.id.item_mm:
                    {
                        ((TextView) view).setTextColor(color);
                        ((TextView) view).setText(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataBase.JURNAL_MONTH)));
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```